# SQL Ordenação e agrupamento

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como eu poderia ordernar essa tabela colocando por ordem da coluna Field name não sendo por ordem alfabética e acompanhando o campo choice a direta. Por exemplo, Cada field name tem varias choices diferentes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está difícil de entender o que deseja. Da a entender que você quer separar os campos de cada linha e reagrupar em uma nova linha, o que é meio absurdo para uma tabela de um banco de dados.

Comment: Se a coluna Field name é alfanumérica que tipo de ordenação você deseja para tal campo?

Comment: @JânioProcópioFerreira Você poderia acrescentar no texto de sua pergunta como deseja a apresentação final? Poste exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Tua pergunta ficou um pouco confusa, mas vamos tentar.

O SQL possui um comando de ordenação, é o `order by` que pode ser `asc` (defult) ou `desc` (ordem decrescente).

basicamente tu deve fazer:

```
select [campos]
from [tabela]
where [condição]
order by [campo ordenado] [asc/desc]
```